# Acknowledging concox GT06N GPS device after receiving login packet

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, gps

I am receiving login packet from my concox GT06N GPS device. Also I have read it. But when I am trying to send response packet (acknowledgement) to device it seems like the response packet is not getting delivered. Because after sending acknowledgement I am not receiving location packet from device.

Below is the code I am using:

```
TcpClient cli = new TcpClient();

IPEndPoint deviceIPE = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CID"].ToString())
  , Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CPORT"]));
cli.Connect(deviceIPE);
logsys.Enqueue("TCP Client created");
using (NetworkStream clientstream = cli.GetStream())
{
    byte[] data = (byte[])sdata1.Dequeue();
    string cip = suser1.Dequeue().ToString();
    string[] acip = new string[2];
    if (cip != "")
    {
        acip = cip.Split(':');
    }
    TechnoComPacket packet = new TechnoComPacket(data);

    string rdata = packet.StringToByteArray(data);

    logsys.Enqueue("Response Packet to be Send Is :" + rdata);

    byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rdata);


    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(rdata);
    clientstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    logsys.Enqueue("Response Packet Sent successfully");
}
```